# Mozilla Thunderbird 3.0.10: Messages are being sent back to me

Tags: email, thunderbird

When I send an email and I get a response, more often than not, in the `To:` is my email address. However, my email address also ends up in the `From:` column.The `reply-from` address is nowhere to be found;so I don't have any address with which I can send my reply, as both of them have just my email address.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there some set-up in my `Tools` > `Options` which is incorrect? The set-up in `Options` is pretty difficult to understand and it doesn't offer any `to` or `reply-from` choices.

This is critical because I just cannot answer my emails because there is no one I can send a reply to.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837753

Comment: I think TB means Thunderbird (email client)

Comment: possible duplicate of [TB3.0.10: Messages being sent back to me ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837753/tb3-0-10-messages-being-sent-back-to-me)

Comment: This does not seem like a Thunderbird problem, it looks more like a Mail Server issue. Please supply some more information about which mail server you are connecting to, which method (POP or IMAP). Also, please post the header of such a mail (removing personal information of course, press Ctrl-U to get the full "raw" e-mail content)